# access the index of the item inside reduce function in dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave

My DataWeave code looks like below:-

```
Result: Data reduce (item,ls={}) -> ls ++ From: {dev: item.warehouse}
```

Is there way to check the index of item object. I need to do conditional based on the index of the item object.

Example:
Item = Data[0] do this ;

```
Result: Data reduce (item,ls={}) -> ls ++ From: {dev: item.warehouse}
```

Item = Data[1] do this ;

```
Result: Data reduce (item,ls={}) -> ls ++ To: {dev: item.warehouse}
```

Original Code looks like below:

```
Result : ( Data  reduce (
             item,ls={}) -> ls ++ 
From:{id: "111",(if (item.sign == "333") {status: "OPEN"} else if (item.sign == "444") {status: "HOLD"} else {status: item.sign})}
```

I need to add "From" whenever the index of Item is odd number and add "To" whenever the index of item is even.

Since I don't have the conditional, I am always getting "From"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't access any indexes, here's the documentation of `reduce`  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/dw-core-functions-reduce

What you can do is count the items yourself by modifying the structure of your accummulator: `ls={counter=0,data={}}`

Now you can use the counter to add one per iteration and keep track of things: `{counter: ls.counter + 1, data: ls.data ++ To: {dev: item.warehouse}}`

As you can understand you would need to add a conditional to differentiate between the `From` and `To`.

If I have time later on I 'll do it for you, or somebody else can beat me to it.

EDIT: here's the best I can do based upon your question, but you should get the idea:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/dw
var inputdata = [{warehouse: 100},{warehouse: 56}, {warehouse:1000}]
---
inputdata reduce (
    (e, acc={c: 0, data: {From: {}, To: {}}}) ->
        {
            c: acc.c+1,
            data: {
                From: if (isEven(acc.c)) (acc.data.From ++ {warehouse: e.warehouse}) else acc.data.From,
                To: if (isEven(acc.c)) acc.data.To else (acc.data.To ++ {warehouse: e.warehouse})
            }
        } 
)
```

Always provide appropriate sample inputs and outputs of your transformation if you want to get the most out of the DW SO community ;)

Comment: I have updated the original code if you help me the conditional that would be great

Comment: Provide input and output sample data please, maybe with an explanation of the algorithm.